# showing that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfies at a point not in the domain of some function $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's say I have a function not defined at $z=0$ and thus written as a composite function.  That is, something in therms of $x$ and $y$ for $z \neq 0$ and $0$ for $z=0$.

To verify that the Cauchy-Riemannequations hold at $z=0$ Seems immediately true since partials wrt $x$ or $y$ of $0$ are obviously $0$.  Am I missing some things?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Give a specific example please.

Comment: The value of a derivative at a point depends on more than the value of the function at that point.  For the partial derivative of $u(x,y)$, say with respect to $x$, to exist at $(0,0)$, we must have existence of the limit$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{u(h,0)-u(0,0)}{h}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your claim that “partials are obviously zero” is (obviously!) false. You cannot use only the value at a single point (in this case $f(0)=0$) to say anything about *how fast the function's value is changing* when you move from that point to nearby points. You must also take the values at the nearby points into account.